# return a struct pointer from a function with return type char*

Tags: c

I have to create a function that, given a student ID, will look through an array of pointers to struct members(students) and return a char pointer to that student. the function should return null if no student is found.

the function prototype below was provided by the professor and cannot be changed, the find id function is correct I believe but I don't know how I'm suppose to return the pointer to the student if the return type is char* and the student type is struct. if someone can point me in the right direction(no pun intended) id appreciate it.

```
char * find_id(int id, struct student * arr[], int n)
```

struct definition

```
struct student {
  int id;
  char * name;
};
```

create student function

```
struct student * create_student(int id, char * name){
  struct student *ptr = (struct student*) malloc( sizeof(struct student));
      if(ptr==NULL){
         return NULL;
       }
  ptr->id = id;
  ptr->name = malloc((strlen(name)+1)* sizeof(char));
      if(ptr->name == NULL){
         free(ptr);
         return NULL;
       }
  strcpy(ptr->name, name);
  return ptr;
}
```

my find_id function

```
char * find_id(int id, struct student * arr[], int n){
    
    for(int i = 0; i<n;i++){
        if(arr[i]->id == id){
            return arr[i];

        }
        else{
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    
}
```

Main function

```
int main(){
char name1[]="ALI";
char name2[]="MOE";
char name3[]="AYA";
char name4[]="RANA";
char name5[]="BOB";
int id1 = 10000;
int id2 = 10001;
int id3 = 10002;
int id4 = 10003;
int id5 = 10004;

struct student *student[4];
student[0] = create_student(id1,name1);
student[1] = create_student(id2,name2);
student[2] = create_student(id3,name3);
student[3] = create_student(id4,name4);
student[4] = create_student(id5,name5);

for(int i=0; i<5;i++){
  free_student(student[i]);
}
assert(strcmp(find_id(10000,student,5),"ALI")==0);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not suppose to return the student's name?

Comment: My guess is that you're supposed to return a char* to the student's name. In the future, any question that looks like, "What does <person X> mean by <statement Y>" your best bet is to ask <person X>. (You should have just asked your professor).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP should have just asked their professor what they wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return a `struct student *` from a function which has a return type of `char *`.

As such, the professor probably asked to return the name of the student, not the student structure itself.